# out keyword: C# to python translation

Tags: c#, python, .net, return, out

I am a beginner python programmer, and trying to understand a c# script. I came across the out keyword, I have read several other threads, but I think i have not been able to understand it completely. So here's a snippet of the script I am trying to understand.

```
void Vector3(out NewVector3 v) {
    double x, y, z; 
    Double(out x);
    Double(out y);
    Double(out z);
    v = NewVector3(x, y, z);
```

A python equivalent of this snippet based on my understanding would be,

```
def Vector3():
    return NewVector(float(),float(),float())
```

is my translation correct?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`out` is used in languages that can't return multiple objects; you pass in a complex object for the function to 'return' by altering the contents.

In Python, just return multiple values (a tuple, really), or in this case, an instance of the `NewVector()` class:

```
return NewVector(0., 0., 0.)
```

Comment: True, and in this case, it seems `x`, `y` and `z` are all zeroes, so this whole function becomes `return 0, 0, 0` :\

Comment: @zvone: or `0.` for a shorthand float value.

Comment: Interesting, I would use `0.`, but `.0` also works :) Anyway, I would also avoid making distinction between `int` and `float`, but that is just me

Comment: I did not know float() == 0., thankyou.